# IIS10 URL Rewrite rule dropping everything after the domain name

Tags: url-rewrite-module

I'm attempting to redirect traffic from an old domain and site to a new site.  However, the routes of my new site, match the old site.
What I would like to see is this

https://my**old**site.com/product-category/tools-accessories/
get redirected to this
https://my**new**site.com/product-category/tools-accessories/

however, all my redirects are going to
https://mynewsite.com and everything else is getting dropped.  I've gone through the help pages, and it looks like a query string can be appended to the new URL, but I don't see a way to append the rest of my URL if it's not a query string.

Is this not possible with the URL Rewrite module in IIS?